# C# How would I convert a group of integer variables to a byte array?

Tags: c#, arrays, sockets

I have a group of integers that I want to send over a socket connection. What would be the cleanest way to convert the following variables into a byte array?

```
int var1 = 1;
int var2 = 2;
int var3 = 3;
```

Because I'm sending data via sockets, I would like to format the data using big-endianness. Thus for the three variables listed, I would want a 12 byte array such that

```
byte[0] = 0;
byte[1] = 0;
byte[2] = 0;
byte[3] = 1;
byte[4] = 0;
byte[5] = 0;
byte[6] = 0;
byte[7] = 2;
byte[8] = 0;
byte[9] = 0;
byte[10] = 0;
byte[11] = 3;
```

My search results are surprisingly coming up empty.

Edit: The suggested duplicate questions are different from what I'm asking. I do not have an "array of integers" or "a single integer" that I want to convert to a byte array. I have a group of individual array variables and am looking for the cleanest solution.

Comment: `Buffer.BlockCopy`...

Comment: *"My search results are surprisingly coming up empty* I don't see how that's possible...I searched for *"convert integers to byte array c# site:stackoverflow.com"* and it returned most of the duplicates for this question. Unless there's something else you were asking that I misunderstood?

Comment: @RufusL I edited my question to  clarify how my question is unique.

Comment: Can you show some sample input and expected output to show what result you're looking for? How to you want to combine the integers so you end up with a single byte array (aside from adding them to an `int[]`, which it sounds like you don't want to do)? Or do you want a `byte[byte[]]` result?

Comment: `byte[] myMessage = new byte[3 * sizeof(int)]; Buffer.BlockCopy(new[] {var1, var2, var3}, 0, myMessage, 0, myMessage.Length);`

Comment: @RufusL I edited my question with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to write a method that takes in a `params int[]` arg, which allows you to pass any number of `int` values to it.

Then you can create a `byte[]` based on the number of arguments, and populate it in a loop.

Since you want a Big-Endian result, we can use `Array.Reverse` to reverse the order of bytes returned from `BitConverter.GetBytes` for each argument, and then we can add each byte to the result array based on the index of the byte and the index of the argument:

```
public static byte[] GetBigEndianBytes(params int[] args)
{
    var result = new byte[args.Length * sizeof(int)];           

    for (var argIndex = 0; argIndex < args.Length; argIndex++)
    {
        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(args[argIndex]).Reverse().ToArray();

        for (var byteIndex = 0; byteIndex < bytes.Length; byteIndex++)
        {
            result[byteIndex + argIndex * sizeof(int)] = bytes[byteIndex];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

In use, this might look like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    int var1 = 1;
    int var2 = 2;
    int var3 = 3;

    var result = GetBigEndianBytes(var1, var2, var3);

    // result = { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3}
```